# Convert list of byte strings to bytearray (byte stream)

Tags: python, python-3.x, arrays

I have a list of hex strings representing bytes, of the form "FF".  I want to convert the whole list to a byte stream so I can send it over a socket (Python 3).  It looks like the bytearray type would work, but I can't find any way to directly convert the list to a bytearray.

I can do it manually in a loop, but figure there must be a better Python way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hexstrings = ["DE", "AD", "BE", "EF"]   # big-endian 0xDEADBEEF

bytes = bytearray(int(x, 16) for x in hexstrings)
bytes = bytearray.fromhex("".join(hexstrings))     # Python 2.6 may need u""
```

If you've got a lot of 'em, it might be worthwhile to see which of those is fastest.

Comment: First code comment: `0xDEADBEEF` is an integer which relates to `hexstrings` only on a bigendian machine. Second code comment: Your code works with python 2.7 *without change*; it would need major surgery to get it to work on earlier versions e.g. `"".join([chr(int(x, 16)) for x in hexstrings])` will do the job for Python 2.1 to 2.7 inclusive.

Comment: The first comment was merely an opportunity to write "Ox Dead Beef" in hex, but you are technically correct -- the best kind of correct! And "big-endian ox dead beef" is arguably even funnier. :-) On the second, it was actually Python 2.6 that insisted on having a Unicode string there, but that seems to be a bug. 2.7 behaves as you state and I've changed that. (`bytearray` was introduced in 2.6, just for the record.)

Answer (score 1):

```
hexlist = ["a9", "00", "85", "c6"]
ba = bytearray(h.decode("hex") for h in hexlist)
```

See also bytearray.fromhex:

> `bytearray.fromhex(string) -> bytearray`
>
> Create a bytearray object from a string of hexadecimal numbers. Spaces between two numbers are accepted. Example:
> bytearray.fromhex('B9 01EF') -> bytearray(b'\xb9\x01\xef').

Answer (score -1):

Refer to :

char* PyByteArray_AsString(PyObject *bytearray)
Return the contents of bytearray as a char array after checking for a NULL pointer

from the [python doc reference](http://docs.python.org/c-api/bytearray.html)

Comment: I'm looking to go the other direction.